# Hive command to remove domain name suffix

Tags: dns, hive

I would like to be able to remove the suffix from the domain names in a hive table.
As there are various types of suffixes (.co.uk, .com, .ac.uk, ...) I am woundering what is the best way to do this?

Comment: This could probably be done with regular expressions, depending on how varied your data turns out to be.  Do you have a sample of your input data to share with us?

Comment: a632.phobos.apple.com   
a1554.phobos.apple.com  
a1207.phobos.apple.com  
a1877.phobos.apple.com  
lnll.googlevideo.com       
a8-19.clients.cdn13.com 
r6---sn-aigllnzk.googlevideo.com        
r1---sn-cg07lues.googlevideo.com        
r4---sn-aiglln6k.googlevideo.com        
r18---sn-aigllnel.googlevideo.com       
r11---sn-aigllnly.googlevideo.com       
r20---sn-aigllnsk.googlevideo.com             
r2---sn-aigllnee.googlevideo.com        
r14---sn-aigllnld.googlevideo.com       
r19---sn-aigllnll.googlevideo.com       
r14---sn-aigllnsd.googlevideo.com

Comment: These all have `.com` as the TLD.  Is that true for the rest of your data?

Comment: no I took a sample as I couldn't copy everything across. there are all sorts of suffixes.

Comment: would it be possible to split the domain and take the last two sections dot delimited?
the command below is not allowed
split(domain,'\\.'),[-2]

Comment: but basically its what i would need. to get the suffix and the section before that in the set of data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to isolate the last two sections of the domain name, which can be done with `regexp_extract`.  Using the portion of your data you posted as a concrete example:

```
hive> DESCRIBE dns_data;
OK
fullname                    string                              
Time taken: 0.871 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM dns_data;
OK
a632.phobos.apple.com
a1554.phobos.apple.com
a1207.phobos.apple.com
a1877.phobos.apple.com
lnll.googlevideo.com
a8-19.clients.cdn13.com
r6---sn-aigllnzk.googlevideo.com
r1---sn-cg07lues.googlevideo.com
r4---sn-aiglln6k.googlevideo.com
r18---sn-aigllnel.googlevideo.com
r11---sn-aigllnly.googlevideo.com
r20---sn-aigllnsk.googlevideo.com
r2---sn-aigllnee.googlevideo.com
r14---sn-aigllnld.googlevideo.com
r19---sn-aigllnll.googlevideo.com
r14---sn-aigllnsd.googlevideo.com
Time taken: 0.589 seconds, Fetched: 16 row(s)
```

`regexp_extract` could be used in the following fashion to isolate the last two strings:

```
hive> SELECT
    >   stripped,
    >   suffix,
    >   split(suffix, "\\.") AS suffix_split
    > FROM (SELECT
    >   regexp_extract(fullname, "^(.*?)\\.((?:[^.]+\\.?){2})$", 1) AS stripped,
    >   regexp_extract(fullname, "^(.*?)\\.((?:[^.]+\\.?){2})$", 2) AS suffix   
    > FROM dns_data
    > ) t;
...
... Lots of MapReduce spam
...
OK
a632.phobos apple.com       ["apple","com"]
a1554.phobos        apple.com       ["apple","com"]
a1207.phobos        apple.com       ["apple","com"]
a1877.phobos        apple.com       ["apple","com"]
lnll        googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
a8-19.clients       cdn13.com       ["cdn13","com"]
r6---sn-aigllnzk    googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r1---sn-cg07lues    googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r4---sn-aiglln6k    googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r18---sn-aigllnel   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r11---sn-aigllnly   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r20---sn-aigllnsk   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r2---sn-aigllnee    googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r14---sn-aigllnld   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r19---sn-aigllnll   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
r14---sn-aigllnsd   googlevideo.com ["googlevideo","com"]
Time taken: 22.073 seconds, Fetched: 16 row(s)
```

Comment: @Javad I'm happy it worked out.  Please accept the answer (the big green checkmark) if you found it useful.

Comment: can you please kinly add some short comments explaining this section of the code regexp_extract(fullname, "^(.*?)\\.((?:[^.]+\\.?){2})$", 1) AS stripped;
to be more precise "^(.*?)\\.((?:[^.]+\\.?){2})$"
thanks again

Comment: @Javad There's probably not enough space here for me to try to give a concise summary of regular expressions.  :)  However, Oracle's Java documentation does offer a primer on Java's implementation of regex - the start of the document trail is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Comment: @Javad Specifically regarding the regular expression used in the answer above, I've loaded it up at https://regex101.com/r/vI3fV6/1 which can give you a better idea of how this specific expression works (there is an "Explanation" window on the right side of the page).  Note that in Java regex strings stored in `String` objects double up on the backslashes (the escape characters themselves have to be escaped), so the expression that's in the regex101.com looks slightly different as a result (but functionally does the same thing).